# Req.file returns [object, object] when trying to upload picture using multer and cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I am trying to save an image from a form using multer and cloudinary but the only thing that gets returned in the request.file and request.body is [object, object]

my app.js file

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const cloudinaryStorage = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET 
});
const storage = cloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    folder: "demo",
    allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png"],
    transformation: [{ width: 500, height: 500, crop: "limit" }]
});
const parser = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/", parser.single("image"), (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.file) // <--- this returns [object, object]
 }
```

html form

```html
<form action="/" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML of your `<form>`.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to examine exactly what `req.file` is? It seems like it's an array of posted files.

Answer (score 2):

Your form doesn't have a file-uploader doohicky. Change the type of your input to `file` instead of `text` and then try.

Also, when you want to inspect an object via `console.log` you should do:

`console.log( JSON.stringify( theObject ) );`

Comment: I accidentally put it as type="text" when I was submitting the question, in my document the input is file type.